# Counting Array in a Collection in Firestore in Android

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to count the array which is contained in a collection. The data is structured like this:

```
{requests=[{name=Jayson, created=1599139605672, from=jayson123, to=marco123, timestamp=2020-09-03T13:26:45+00:00}]}
```

In the example above I would like to count how many arrays does the `requests` collection contains, which in that case is 1.

I am using `snapshot.getData().size()` but it is always returning 1. Can you help me pls.

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know the size of a list type field in a document, you have to:

1. Read the document as a [DocumentSnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentSnapshot)
2. Get the field by name - it will be a generic List type object
3. Use the `size()` method on that List.

It will be something like this, assuming you have a snapshot:

```
DocumentSnapshot snapshot = ...
List<Object> requests = (List<Object>) snapshot.get("requests");
int size = requests.size();
```